# How to resume a suspended Windows Workflow Service from a client?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I have created a Workflow Server and Hosted it in IIS. I have a sample site which has a service reference and call the workflow service by creating the service object. Everything works fine.

But in case an exception occurred in the workflow,  it will suspend the workflow. I can see it in the SQL Persistence store DB.

But how can i resume this workflow from the client site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. When a workflow is suspended, you have to explicitly resume it using Appfabric. But If the workflow is Abandon, workflow service will resume the workflow when the next hit comes. Until then it will be saved in the SQL Persistence store.

In order to change the default behavior for the Unhandled Exception please put the below in your `<behavior>` section of the web.config.

```
<workflowUnhandledException action="Abandon" />
```

I tried this. When the exception happened it will go to the catch and execute what ever command I have given. But it does not suspend the workflow. It just abandon it. Later I fix the issue and call the second part of my workflow using CorreationIDs , it resumes the workflow and completes it.

Hope this helps a poor soul out there like me. Workflow Foundation does not have much documentation and almost all the demos are in console applications which is basic. It is a struggle. :(